# Dictionary only reads first string

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary

I want to enter in a dict all lowercase letters and count them. My input should be something like:

```
John Steinbeck:
     *****The Grapes of Wrath*****
     *****East of Eden*****
```

And the output should be:

```
e 5
```

My code far now is:

```
from easyinput import read
n = read(str)
letters = {}

for i in n:
    if i.isspace():
        n = read(str)
    elif i.islower():
        if i not in letters:
            letters[i] = 1
        else:
            letters[i] += 1
    n = read(str)
print(letters)
```

I tried also when i == ' ' but it does not work. I do not understand why letters are not stored in dict, only the first word of each row is stored.

Taking only the first 'sentence' (John Steinbeck:) dict should return

```
{'o': 1, 'h': 1, 'n': 2, 't': 1, 'e': 2, 'i': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'k': 1}
```

But it only returns

```
{'o': 1, 'h': 1, 'n': 1}
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Code is not finished, I only want to solve the dictionary problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter()` like this:

```py
from collections import Counter

s = '''John Steinbeck:
     *****The Grapes of Wrath*****
     *****East of Eden*****'''

counter = Counter(c for c in s if c.islower())

print(counter)
```

Which results in:

```py
Counter({'e': 5, 'o': 3, 'h': 3, 'n': 3, 't': 3, 'a': 3, 'r': 2, 's': 2, 'f': 2, 'i': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'k': 1, 'p': 1, 'd': 1})
```

If you want to know which character is the most common one, you can use this:

```py
counter.most_common(1)
```

Which results in:

```py
[('e', 5)]
```